# Property 'currentTime' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript.Currently i am trying to learn the interface in TypeScript.Here is my code :

```
interface ClockInterface{
    currentTime:Date;
    setTime(d:Date):void;
}
class Clock implements ClockInterface{
    currentTime:Date;[**[ts] Property 'currentTime' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.]**
    setTime(d:Date){
        this.currentTime =d;
    }
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're in strict mode (specifically, the `strictNullChecks` option is true).

So a variable of type `Date` must be of type `Date`. [It may not be null or undefined](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html). Since you're not initializing the `currentTime` in the constructor, the variable is undefined until the `setTime()` method is called. So you're violating your type definition.

Either initialize the variable in the constructor, or change the type to `Date | undefined`, or change the compiler settings.

Answer (score 0):

To remove this error go into the "tsconfig.json" and remove strict="true". It works for me, it checks strictnullcheck error.

Answer (score 0):

Add (!) sing after name:

```js
someField!: string;
```

**OR**

Open TypeScript config file

`tsconfig.json` and add this code to compiler options

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
    //   ...
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
    //   ...
  }
```

Note: it will make static analysis weaker